# Next birthdays with fql - fbook

Tags: sql, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using Facebook graph API I have the following which shows this months birthdays of a users friends

```
SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday_date FROM user
WHERE (substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) = "04") AND uid IN
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name
```

What I actually want to show is the next 10 birthdays, so it crosses months probably as month is close to end, but, facebook does like the NOW in queries so I'm a little lost how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - here's how ya do it!

```
$dd = date(d);

$mm = date(m);

SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday_date FROM user
WHERE (((substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) = "$mm") AND 
(substr(birthday_date, 3, 2) > "$dd") OR (substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) > "$mm")))
AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by birthday_date asc
```

Comment: Just a quick note, this will not work when reacing the end of the year (fewer and fewer will people will show up as the year reaches its end). Only once you hit the 1st an January will it start working properly again.